# How can i switch TTL index on and off using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a user account on my app, and have that user deleted after a certian amount of time if this user hasn't confirmed his account, and switch TTL off if the user has confirmed his account.

Here is my Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
  ,
  isConfirmed: {
    type: Boolean
  },
  code: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    expires: 3600,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already added `TTL index` on `createdAt` field, you can easily turn it off by deleting the `createdAt` field on successful account confirmation.

If a document has `createdAt` value and it is older than the specified time, then it will be deleted. But, if you delete that field on account confirmation, it wont be deleted. Thus you need to delete `createdAt` field on account confirmation.

If you want to keep `createdAt` field, you can add `TTL index` on some temporary field like `expireAfter` and delete it on account confirmation.

```
  expireAfter: {
    type: Date,
    expires: 3600,
    default: Date.now
  }
```

After account confirmation.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id : user_id},{$unset : {expireAfter:1}})
```

From official docs :

> MongoDB will automatically delete documents from the
>   collection when the document’s createdAt value is older than the
>   number of seconds specified in expireAfterSeconds (in your case `expires` ).

For more information read [MongoDB TTL index docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)